# Archiva keeps showing deleted SNAPSHOT version artifacts in Browse

Tags: maven, archiva

Our Archiva Repository (version 2.2.1) is configured with both a snapshot and a release repositories.

Snapshot repository is configured with 1 retention count, 1 day old, and to delete released snapshots.
And also, the repository-purge consumer is enabled.

The thing is I can see (in the server, in the snapshot repository folder) that the snapshot artifact files are being removed, but when i BROWSE the Archiva, it is still showing that snapshots, and the artifact (although with 0b size)

[Versions of the artifact, all repositories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYBRS.png)

[Artifacts for 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLsWX.png)

Is this behavior intended, or something in the purge process is failing and not removing this references?
Is it possible to adjust Archiva to delete this references (apart from manually delete the snapshot versions)?

Comment: It seems there was a "Database scanning" process that was in charge to clean up the database, but was removed in Archiva 1.4
[link]https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/ARCHIVA/Database+Scanning

Comment: It looks like it is maybe a problem with the Jackrabbit database not being purged, as the Search is working OK.

Only the BROWSE is showing purged SNAPSHOT artifacts

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue that has been resolved in the unreleased version of **2.2.4** of Archiva. They will not release a **2.2.4** version, but are working on a **3.0.0** version that contains the fix for the bug. The date for the release has not been confirmed yet, but the fix is available : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MRM-1958